# What is the articulatory nature of [lʲ] and how is it normally lenited world wide, especially compared to [l]?

Tags: phonetics, historical-linguistics

[l] is lenited in some languages like English (dark L), and in Polish (Ł). How is [lʲ] developed further if it does?

Answer (score 3):

There is a tendency to develop into a palatal approximant, for instance [in Spanish](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/cons.htm) *ʎ* became *ʒ* and eventually *x*; there is also a modern shift of *ʎ* to *j* whence *ʒ* and similar outcomes especially in Latin American Spanish. There is a parallel development in Quechua where earlier [lʲ] as preserved in Cuzco Quechua becomes [ʒ] in Imbabura Quechua. Other languages with the historical change of [ʎ,lʲ] to [j] include Hungarian and French.